# Plotting black and white images using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, grayscale

I am trying to plot this image:

[image: grey scale image]

using this code:

```
img = mpimg.imread("image_name")
plt.figure()
plt.title("decrypted image")
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
```

and the result is this image:
[image: colored image]

I tried switching the previous `imshow` with this one:

```
imgplot = plt.imshow(img, cmap='Greys')
```

and the result is this image:
[image: wrong grey_scaled image]

How can I plot this original grey-scale image exactly how it looks?

Comment: try using "Greys_r" as the colormap

Comment: it worked , thanks for your answer @Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I have to use "Greys_r" as the colormap instead of "Greys"